# UIBarButtonItem not clickable

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, clickable

I have a very tricky problem and after long searching (google, stackoverflow, ...) i didn't get the solution that works for me.

Let me introduce you in my current choosen architecture:

1. I have a a AppDelegate, which has a UIView that contains a UINavigationController and the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: contains:

   ```
   UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 400)];
     UIViewController *myController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
     myController.view = myView;


         FSCScrumRootView * myRootView = [[FSCScrumRootView alloc] initWithNibName:@"FSCScrumRootView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

         [myController.view addSubview:myRootView.navigation.view];

         [self.window addSubview:myController.view];

         [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
         return YES;
       }
   ```
2. In my FSCScrumRootView (inherits from UIViewController) i init the view like this:

   ```
   - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil 
   { 
   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

   if (self) {
   // Custom initialization
   self.navigation = [[[UINavigationController alloc] init] autorelease];
   self.scrumProjectsList = [[[FSCScrumProjectListView alloc] init] initWithNibName:@"FSCScrumProjectListView" bundle:nil];
   [navigation pushViewController:scrumProjectsList animated:YES]; 

   [navigation view]; 
   } 
   return self; 
   }
   ```
3. In my FSCScrumProjectListView (it is inherited from UITableViewController) i have implemented the viewDidLoad as following:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad 
   { 
   [super viewDidLoad]; 

   //Set the title 
   self.navigationItem.title = @"Scrum Projects";

   UIBarButtonItem *myRefreshButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Refresh" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshList)] autorelease]; 
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = myRefreshButton;

   UIBarButtonItem *myLogoutButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(logout)]; 
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myLogoutButton;


   //Initialize the toolbar
   toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
   toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

   //Set the toolbar to fit the width of the app.
   [toolbar sizeToFit];

   //Caclulate the height of the toolbar
   CGFloat toolbarHeight = [toolbar frame].size.height;

   //Get the bounds of the parent view
   CGRect rootViewBounds = self.parentViewController.view.bounds;

   //Get the height of the parent view.
   CGFloat rootViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(rootViewBounds);

   //Get the width of the parent view,
   CGFloat rootViewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(rootViewBounds);

   //Create a rectangle for the toolbar
   CGRect rectArea = CGRectMake(0, rootViewHeight - toolbarHeight, rootViewWidth, toolbarHeight);

   //Reposition and resize the receiver
   [toolbar setFrame:rectArea];

   //Create a button
   UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                initWithTitle:@"Info" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(info_clicked:)];

   [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:infoButton,nil]];

   //Add the toolbar as a subview to the navigation controller.
   [self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];

   //Reload the table view
   [self.tableView reloadData]; 
   }
   ```
4. This results finally in the following screen (as i'd like to have it):
   [View iOS Mockup of current result](http://twitpic.com/4qz7r8)

**The Problem:**
My Problem now is, that i can click ONLY on the Refresh Button. The other two buttons (Info and Logout) cannot be clicked. And i don't understand why? What I am doing wrong here?

Your help is kindly appreceated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People, i have found the reason for my problem and i have to say, it was a very very silly one.

The first line of this project was responsible for all the troubels:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 400)];
```

Since the View i created there is only sized 200x400, it is to small to recognize any events that appear in the outside of this view (although everything is visible).

If i change the size of this view, all works as expected:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 500)];
```

But the more dynamic solution would probably be:

```
CGRect cgRect =[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize cgSize = cgRect.size;
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cgSize.width, cgSize.height)];
```

Maybe there is an even better solution for getting the dynamic screen size?

Answer (score 0):

Try autoreleasing the second two buttons like your first one (the refresh).

```
UIBarButtonItem *myLogoutButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(logout)]autorelease];



UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                             initWithTitle:@"Info" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(info_clicked:)]autorelease];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this solution doesn't solved the problem )-: I tried both ways: `UIBarButtonItem *myLogoutButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(logout)] autorelease];` and 
`[myLogoutButton release];`